# how to display custom permission message

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I want to display a custom message to the user for app permission. I am using `Plugin.Permissions` for App permission. When i run the current code and run application this popup message display `Allow {App Name} to access this device location?`. Below is the function currently i am using.

```
public static async Task<bool> GetPermissions()
{
    bool permissionsGranted = true;

    var permissionsStartList = new List<Permission>()
    {
        Permission.Location,           
        Permission.Camera
    };

    var permissionsNeededList = new List<Permission>();
    try
    {
        foreach (var permission in permissionsStartList)
        {
            var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(permission);
            if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                permissionsNeededList.Add(permission);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }

    var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(permissionsNeededList.ToArray());

    try
    {
        foreach (var permission in permissionsNeededList)
        {
            var status = PermissionStatus.Unknown;
            //Best practice to always check that the key exists
            if (results.ContainsKey(permission))
                status = results[permission];
            if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted || status == PermissionStatus.Unknown)
            {
                permissionsGranted = true;
            }
            else
            {
                permissionsGranted = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    return permissionsGranted;
}
```

Thanks for your help and comments

Comment: In the iOS, you can change the description by yourself, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/security-privacy?tabs=windows. However, you can't change the title of the message because it is defined by system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly there is no way to customize the text in the permission dialogs.

These are system dialogs and the app has no control over their content.

Quote from https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#perm-request

> When your app receives PERMISSION_DENIED from checkSelfPermission(), you need to prompt the user for that permission. Android provides several methods you can use to request a permission, such as requestPermissions(), as shown in the code snippet below. **Calling these methods brings up a standard Android dialog, which you cannot customize.**
>
> **How this is displayed to the user depends on the device Android version as well as the target version of your application, as described in the Permissions Overview.**